# If a matrix is scaled and an algorithm is run on said matrix how is the scaling undone?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image]

Above is the assignment.

There is a certain non-square matrix $A$ made up of functions that will be used by the gradient descent algorithm to find the coefficients, $x'$, to estimate a $b$ (basically least squares).

Therefor $x'$ can be stated as: $x'=(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$

However, this matrix was very ill-conditioned and was therefore scaled by a matrix $W$ i.e. $Z=AW$ and thus $z'=(Z^TZ)^{-1}Z^Tb$

This means the gradient descent algorithm will return the coefficients for $z'$  and not $x'$ so there needs to be a transform of $z'$ to $x'$. How can I find that transformation manipulating the equations from the assignment?

What I attempted:

$z'=((AW)^T (AW))^{-1}(AW)^Tb$

And after doing some manipulation I ended with this however I am not sure it is correct and it is not very useful.

$z'=A^{-1}*W^{-1}b$

I attempted another route by impulse and this was to use the diagonal scaling matrix $W$ as a projection basis and project $z'$ to that basis:

$x'=W(W^TW)^{-1}W^Tz'$

For some reason which I did not understand this actually worked. However, I would like to solve it as intended by manipulating the equations and not by chance. Hope someone can see how. I however do believe that this is the correct answer but would like to see how.